# Sql, get all possible min values by group

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's what the table is like:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ProductId      ProductType      SupplierId       Price       Date
    10001          Toy1             3                20          2011-10-20
    10001          Toy1             5                23          2011-11-29
    10002          Book1            3                20          2010-12-29
    10004          Book2            4                12          2013-2-11
    10004          Book2            3                25          2014-1-1
    10004          Book2            5                23          2012-9-18
```

I need a query to get each supplier's lowest priced product, so the result after running the query on above table would be:

```
----------------------------------
   SupplierId      ProductType
   3               Toy1
   3               Book1
   4               Book2
   5               Toy1
   5               Book2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a subquery in the `where` clause or aggregation and a join:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.price = (select min(price)
                 from table t2
                 where t2.supplierid = t.supplierid
                );
```

EDIT:

The version with aggregation is:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select supplierId, min(price) as minprice
      from table t
      group by supplierId
     ) ts
     on ts.supplierId = t.supplierId and ts.minprice = t.price;
```

Under some circumstances, this could perform better than the previous version.  If performance is an issue on larger tables, it is important to test both in your environment, along with the proper indexes.

Comment: what does t2 stand for? The second table is the result I want, not a table

Comment: `t` is a table alias.  This gives you all the fields associated with the minimum priced products.  You can just select `SupplierId` and `ProductType` if that is all you want.

Comment: This will error if a supplier has two products tied for the lowest price

Comment: @qwerty13579 . . . Excuse me?  It will not. It will return both products, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: Actually you're right; it won't error because you have the SUM() in the subquery.  The NOT EXISTS structure will produce a much better query plan, however.

Comment: cool, this works, thanks. I usually use alias like "tableName as t1" and forget I can omit the "as" sometimes. I didn't downvote, I'll choose yours as answer.

Comment: Be aware that this will run a "subquery" for each result.. if you have thousands of records it will execute it thousands of times.  Maybe a Join and a Group by would be better ?

Comment: @Fenwick . . . Many people think the `as` is clutter in the `from` clause (this is opinion) because it adds nothing.  Oracle has never supported it.  On the other hand, MS Access requires it.  On the other hand, `as` in the `select` is quite useful, because it prevents problems with missing commas.

Comment: @Fabrizio . . . This *will* run a subquery.  With an index on `table(supplierId, price)` it should be as performant -- if not more so -- than any other method because the "subquery" will be a scan or lookup in an index.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes it will be a lookup, but still multiple times instead than a one time hit.  I like to reduce disk accesses as much as possible.  Running a query similar to this on a server with over 3.2M records was taking 5 to 10 minutes, with join and group by took less than 30 seconds (live server with a lot of other queries running at the same time).  If it is a one time query, then no issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.SupplierID, a.ProductType
FROM table a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table b WHERE b.SupplierID = a.SupplierID and b.Price < a.Price)
```